# Detect back button press while dialog is open in flutter

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog, flutter, flutter-layout

I am creating an app in a flutter in which I need to display an alert dialog. And this is not a dismissible dialog. But when I press the back button on android it is getting dismissed. I have tried using WillPopScope widget to detect back press events. I am able to detect back button press using WillPopScope but this is not working while the dialog is open. Any suggestion and guide will be really helpful. Thanks.

Dialog creation snippet:

```
void buildMaterialDialog(
  String dialogTitle,
  String dialogContent,
  String negativeBtnText,
  String positiveBtnText,
  String positiveTextUri) {

showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return new AlertDialog(
        title: new Text(dialogTitle),
        content: new Text(dialogContent),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              //Function called
              _updateDialogNegBtnClicked(isCancelable);
            },
            child: new Text(negativeBtnText),
          ),
          new FlatButton(
            onPressed: () => launch(positiveTextUri),
            child: new Text(positiveBtnText),
          ),
        ],
      );
    });}
```

Comment: Do you want to detect backpress or to prevent closing of dialog?

Comment: I want to prevent dialog from closing

Comment: could you share the snippet @anmol.majhail

Answer (score 200, accepted):

Back button won't close the dialog.

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false, // False will prevent and true will allow to dismiss
      child: AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Title'),
        content: Text('This is Demo'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            child: Text('Go Back'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: thats great. But all this time I have been returning a Future inside the onWillPop, like `onWillPop:(){return Future.value(false);}` . never knew it could work without!

Comment: or we can use '() async => false'

Comment: @MaciejStramski that's actually the preferred way. It saves me from suppressing warnings in my IDE regarding unfulfilled return type declarations (Future<Bool>).

Comment: if you already use `WillPopScope()`, `barrierDismissible = false` is no longer needed tho

Comment: If the view on witch you open the dialog has WillPopScope already, it will trigger that too. I found this where people discuss it, but seems like there is no solution.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47088

Comment: I keep going back to this.. I'm so stoopid XD

Answer (score 5):

Guys! I'm from 2023) method WillPopScope is update:

```
PopScope(canPop: false, child: AlertDialog())
```

Answer (score 2):

Because my reputation not enough to comment on the accepted answer, I want to give other alternative for `onPressed: () {}`. You can use `onPressed: () => null`. No warning will pop up.

Answer (score 1):

Three ways to stop dialog getting closed by Android Back Button

**Option one:**

```
           onWillPop: () {
                          return Future.value(false);
                        },
```

**Option Two:**

```
    onWillPop: () async {
                          return false;
                        },
```

**Option Three:**

```
 onWillPop: () {}, // This will give surpress warning, try to avoid this one.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: _onBackPressed,
          child: Scaffold(
            
          ),
        );
      }
    
      Future<bool> _onBackPressed() async {
        return await showDialog(
            context: context, builder: (context) => ExitAppDialogBox());
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

easy way

```
@override
```

Widget build(BuildContext context)
{

return WillPopScope(

```
  onWillPop: () async{
    final value = await showDialog<bool>(
        context: context,
        builder: (context){
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Alert"),
            content: Text("Do you want to Exit ?."),
            actions: [
              TextButton(onPressed: (){
                Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
              }, child: Text("No")),
              TextButton(onPressed: (){
                Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
              }, child: Text("Yes")),
            ],
          );
        });

    if(value != null){
      return Future.value(value);
    }else{
     return Future.value(false);
    }

  },
  child: Scaffold()
```

);